# Suggest suitable time series like ML model

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, prediction

We have data (1901 to 2002) in this schema:

```
Fotrnight, Temp, Precipitation, WetDayFreq, (and other env variables), Cholera_cases
```

we have o**ne such table for each village of three states**. And we want to predict Cholera cases, given fortnight, village name (lat/long), env variables etc.

Where,

```
Fortnight: 2 weeks time period. One year data is divided into 26 fortnights.
Cholera_cases: are the no of cholera cases in that fortnight.
```

As per i think, time series model is not applicable here as we have one time series per village, and we can't have one model for each village. Or is it possible?

Please, is there any way that we can combine time series or any other alternative approach to fit this kind of data???

Answer (score 0):

You can have one model per village, that's not a problem. And you probably have enough training data to build these models.

BUT I would suggest a different approach. People try to model time-series when they don't have background information on what is driving the process. Or maybe they have that information but it's hard to understand or use.

In your case, it looks like you have very useful information in climate variables. You should first understand and model the relationship between weather and the start of a cholera outbreak. If successful, this will allow you to predict when a cholera outbreak will **start**.

There is a good chance that a logistic regression will work. Your climate variables are your inputs and your output will say whether or not an outbreak is about to start.

(By the way, you will need to discover the correct definition of the *minimum number of cases of cholera which constitute an outbreak*, and you may need to tweak this number during your exploration.)

Now once cholera has come to a village, it will stay even if the weather gets better. So now you need another approach to predict the **duration of the outbreak**.

You could just compute the average duration of an outbreak, but this average may not be representative. My feeling is that either it will be, or the duration will be linear in the number of concurrent cholera cases (I don't know how cholera spreads or how long people are infectious before showing symptoms etc.).

If you then want to predict the number of cases during the outbreak, then a time-series approach may be appropriate. Make sure you train, validate and predict only on outbreak data, not inter-outbreak data.